# In an Active FTP connection, can I define client port/ports to use?

Tags: ftp, port-forwarding, port

I'm going throught a connection that only bypasses some ports, previously defined.
I need to stablish an FTP connection throught it but, I need to know the ports that will be used to define them on the bypasser.
For example, I can go throught SFTP because on my bypasser I set port 22 and then it works fine. But I can't go throught FTP because I only know the listen port (21) but I don't know the transfer port, because it's random. But, if I could know/define the client port or a range, it would work.

So... Is there any FTP client that let's you define the client listen port in an active FTP connection?

Comment: If it's an active connection it shouldn't be random. It's using port 20/21 on the server side and actively tell the server your port. On a passive connection the server would tell you the port to connect to.

Comment: @Seth this is exactly what I'm triying, I know that server part will be 21 listening and 20 serving data, but I need to define the listening data port on the client to make it work. Do you know a FTP client that let's you define the client port? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FTP/FTPS and SFTP are different beasts. If you're using SFTP, as implied by the mention of port 22 and comments, you need to be able to establish a SSH connection. A SSH connection to the server and you won't be able to actively define which ports to use.

For FTP and FTPS if you're using an active connection you would be able to do this by sending your PORT command. It depends on the client you're using how to set this up and it will be visible in the control channel command flow.

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning 21-listening, 20-data transfer. SFTP it was only a test, what I need is to make FTP work like that.
Do you know and any FTP software that lets you define client PORT?
Thanks!

Comment: Quite possibly many do it. Among them is FileZilla.

Comment: I've already checked Filezilla and WinSCP and none of them can (or I didn't find it)... I'm thinking about taking some opensource and modify it, but I thought that already one of them had that option.... :(

Comment: [Filezilla Network ocnfiguration](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Active_mode_2) seems pretty straight forward that it's using port 20 in most cases and in addition you could try to use [post login commands](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Post_login_commands). On the other hand if SFTP is working ... just use that and be done with it.